# Number of elements in a finite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

Is the following true?

Let $G$ be a **finite abelian group** with a minimal generating set $S$. By minimal generating set I mean we cannot reduce the cardinality further. Let $S=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_k\}$ with orders $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n$ respectively. Then the group $G$ has $r_1r_2\cdots r_n$ elements.

For example $G=\{e,a,b,c,ab,bc,ca,abc\}$ Take $S=\{a,b,c\}$ Then $|G|=2\times2\times2=8$.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce the cardinality further"? Do you mean "there is no proper subset of $S$ that generates", or do you mean "there is no set with smaller cardinality than that of $S$ that generates"?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Since he says "reduce the cardinality" it would not have occuured to me to doubt that it was the second of thise two interpretations that was intended.

Answer (score 7):

No this is not true in general. Let $G = \langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$ with $|a|=2$, $|b|=4$. Then $\{ ab,b \}$ is a minimal generating set (in any sense), but they both have order $4$, whereas the group has order $8$.

Of course by the Fundamental Theorem, there always exsists a minimal generating set with the property you describe, such as $\{ a, b \}$ in the above example.

Comment: By fundamental theorem
$G \cong \mathbb{Z}/p_i^{a_i}\mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p_r^{a_r}\mathbb{Z}$

where the primes may not be distinct. Then how you are claiming the existence of such set?

Comment: @Max: The structure theorem has an alternative  form, $G\cong C_{d_1}\oplus C_{d_2}\oplus\cdots\oplus C_{d_n}$ where each $d_i$ divides the next. That form does produce a minimal number of cyclic summands.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g_1,g_2\dots g_n$ be the generators for the group, then every element of the group can be seen as $g_1^{a_1}g_2^{a_2}\dots g_n^{a_n}$ where $0\leq a_i< |g_i|$. This tells us $|G|\leq\prod\limits_{i=1}^n|g_i|$.

The inequality can be sharp however, consider the group $\mathbb Z_4+\mathbb Z_6$ of order $24$. The set $\{(1,2),(1,1)\}$ is a minimal and minimum generating set of the group since the group is not cyclic. On the other hand the product of the orders of the elements is $144$.